# ORM-like feature on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if there was a framework of some kind that enable us to create classes that will mainly fetch data from an API to populate itself.

I was looking at core data, but I don't think core data is what I'm looking for since it aims to persist data inside the app.

In case I wasn't clear enough, I want an easy way to do this:

```
@interface MyUser{
    NSUInteger id; // user id form the database
    NSString *first_name;
    NSString *last_name;
    ...
}
@end
```

Is there anything inside(or outside) iOS that would help me with that, or I'll just have to fetch a JSON and populate it myself?

Comment: RestKit bridges JSON and Core Data. So does AFIncrementalStore, but I'm not sure if it's been updated in a while. Also, check out Mantle by GitHub.

Comment: Please, people that wants to close consider providing a comment so I know what's going on.

Comment: @AaronBrager I'm thinking about Mantle, seems the best way to go between those options. Make it an answer.

Comment: People want to close the question because, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  (Which is basically what you're doing.)

Comment: The 2.0 branch has a lot of improvements, btw: https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/tree/2.0-development

Comment: hey @PatrickBassut try this lib https://github.com/LakithaRav/OLCOrm

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother using any framework, you'll struggle to find one that suits your needs exactly.

Better to roll your own system, it's pretty simple.

Make a subclass of NSObject, give it an `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSCache` object to store data fetched from the remote server.

Implement [`-resolveInstanceMethod:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html) to read/write to the data in the dictionary/cache/remote server.

There's a good example here showing roughly what you want: https://github.com/davedelong/Demos/blob/master/DynamicStorage/DynamicStorage/DDDynamicStorageObject.m follow through that code, read the documentation for anything you don't understand. It's fairly simple stuff once you get your head around it.

Comment: Quite so. One point...  It's so simple to handle JSON now in iOS, there's often little reason to not simply "leave it as JSON" if you're just dealing with a less important or incidental set of data.